# Have program continue to run until a certain value has been exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having a little trouble with this assignment:
**Write a program using a while statement that lets the user enter a a series of numbers. Each number should be multiplied by 10 and the result stored in a variable named product.  The loop should iterate as long as the product contains a value less than 10,000.

*Here is what I have so far:*

```
def multiplication():
    tracker = 9999
    userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
    product = (userInput * 10)
    print (product)
    while product <= tracker:
```

I'm not really sure what to do after the while statement that will make the program loop back up if the product is lower than the tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to expand on the code others have posted by explaining the differences between your code and theirs. And some programming conventions which - are fine if you don't remember them come tomorrow.

```
def multiplication():
    tracker = 9999
    userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
    product = (userInput * 10)
    print (product)
    while product <= tracker:
```

First, you don't need a variable to hold the value, you can if you want to. Since it is a constant, a value that doesn't change, the convention is for the name of the variable to be all uppercase letters.

If you are wondering why everyone is using 10000 instead of 9999 as seen in the next line of your code:

```
while product <= tracker:
```

When you are using comparison operators, in your line you are looking for product to be less than or equal to tracker. Which in this case, the loop will continue checking until the evaluation becomes false. Is product equal to 9999? True, and it will do another check. If you ask it:

```
while product < 10000
```

will be essentially the same, but easier to understand since you aren't changing the problem requirements.

Now, you had the right idea with your code. 
All you have to do is move the line with the while loop above userInput.

```
def multiplication():
    TRACKER = 10000
    while product < TRACKER:
        userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
        product = (userInput * 10)
        print (product)
```

The reason we do this is because we need a way to keep asking for the userInput and calculating the product. Which is done by placing the statements inside the while loop. And the while loop in turn is going to exit from the loop when the condition stops being True.

We then need to initialize the variable product or python is going to blow up. So we place the variable declaration before the while loop, because if we were to place it within the while loop it will be re-declared.

Finally, the problem statement asks for the product of each time the user enters a number. That's my understanding anyhow, which may be mistaken. To do that we need to keep adding the values entered into the variable, which is done be grabbing the old value plus the new value. I'll show you the shorthand for that.

```
def multiplication():
    TRACKER = 10000
    product = 0
    while product < TRACKER:
        userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
        product += (userInput * 10)
        print (product)
```

What helps before writing any code is to write it out by hand, on pen and paper. And execute each line out loud. You can also write out comments inside the function before writing the code itself. Write the comments on what its supposed to do, in plain english. Once you got the logic down, you can replace the comments with code.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value of product to `0` and move the while loop above the ***userInput*** statement:

```
def multiplication():
    tracker = 10000
    product = 0
    while product < tracker:
        userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
        product = userInput * 10
        print(product)
```

if you are looking to create a ***recursive*** function, you can return the call to `multiplication()`. like this:

```
def multiplication():
    tracker = 10000
    userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: "))
    product = userInput * 10
    print(product)
    while product < tracker:
        return multiplication()

# also, after you have **defined** your function, 
# don't forget to call it in your program outside of the definition
multiplication()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. The while loop will start because product is less than tracker and will continue until product is greater than tracker.

```
def multiplication():
    tracker = 9999 
    product = 0
    while product <= tracker:
        userInput = int(input("Enter a value to be multiplied by 10: ")) 
        product = (userInput * 10) 
        print (product)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define `product = 0` in our function argument to begin. Then we can `multiply the user input by 10` and assign to `product` in one statement, putting this inside the `while` loop this will prompt user for input while `product < 10000`. Once the condition is exceeded we can `return` that value.

```
def something(product = 0):
    while product < 10000:
        product = int(input('Enter a number: ')) * 10
    return product

print(something())
```

Comment: first off nice name! But functions most certainly do not need to always return a value... If a function does not require to return a value that needs to be used later in the program, there is no need to return anything.

Comment: @PixelEinstein removed comment :) , ty for name compliment, I fancy yours as well!